# Null property selection using named scopes/lambda in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

I have an object `JobBreakdown` that `has_one :invoice`.  If a JobBreakdown has an invoice (i.e. invoice_id is not nil) then it is considered *INVOICED*.  If not, it is consider *UNINVOICED*.  Users want to be able to select from a drop down box Invoiced or Uninvoiced and have correct records show up.

How would I write a named scope to test and return the right records?  Something along the lines of

```
named_scope :is_invoiced, lambda {|is_invoiced| {:conditions => :invoice.nil? == is_invoiced}}
```

NB: I am using ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, this is the right syntax for rails 2.x but at least it'll give you an idea of how to do that.

```
named_scope :is_invoiced, lambda { |is_invoiced| :condition => is_invoiced ? "invoice IS NOT NULL" : "invoice IS NULL" }
```

or maybe even something like this:

```
named_scope :is_invoiced, lambda { |is_invoiced| :condition => "invoice IS #{is_invoiced ? 'NOT' : ''} NULL" }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question.  Users will determine whether they want to search for job breakdowns with a null invoice, OR job breakdowns with a NON null invoice.  Needs to be the option for both.  That scope will only return me the null ones.

Comment: Sorry. I did misunderstand your question. I've updated my answer.